# TabControl overlays Minimize, Maximize and Close button of window

Tags: c#, uwp

If I create for example 12 Tabs at start of my app the tabpages are overlapping the Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons,

I have used the official sample from Microsoft:

https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/TabViewPages/TabViewWindowingSamplePage.xaml.cs

I only changed the number of tabs created at start to 12 like this:

```
// Main Window -- add some default items
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    Tabs.TabItems.Add(CreateNewTVI($"Item {i}", $"Page {i}"));
}
```

And then this happens:
[image]

And I really don't know why this happens

Edit:

The Xaml Code:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <muxc:TabView x:Name="Tabs"                           
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                
        <muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
            <Grid x:Name="ShellTitlebarInset" Background="Transparent" />
        </muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
        <muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
            <Grid x:Name="CustomDragRegion" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="188"/>
        </muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
    </muxc:TabView>
</Grid>
```

The MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    Tabs.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // Extend into the titlebar
    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

    coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;

    var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent;

    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(CustomDragRegion);
    // Main Window - add some tabs
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        Tabs.TabItems.Add(CreateNewTVI($"Item {i}", $"Page {i}"));
    }
}
private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    // To ensure that the tabs in the titlebar are not occluded by shell
    // content, we must ensure that we account for left and right overlays.
    // In LTR layouts, the right inset includes the caption buttons and the
    // drag region, which is flipped in RTL. 

    // The SystemOverlayLeftInset and SystemOverlayRightInset values are
    // in terms of physical left and right. Therefore, we need to flip
    // then when our flow direction is RTL.
    if (FlowDirection == FlowDirection.LeftToRight)
    {
        CustomDragRegion.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayRightInset;
        ShellTitlebarInset.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
    }
    else
    {
        CustomDragRegion.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
        ShellTitlebarInset.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayRightInset;
    }

    // Ensure that the height of the custom regions are the same as the titlebar.
    CustomDragRegion.Height = ShellTitlebarInset.Height = sender.Height;
}

private TabViewItem CreateNewTVI(string header, string dataContext)
{
    var newTab = new TabViewItem()
    {
        IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SymbolIconSource()
        {
            Symbol = Symbol.Placeholder
        },
        Header = header,
        Content = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "This is a text:\n" + dataContext, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            FontSize = 25,
        }
    };
    return newTab;
}
```

Comment: You are overlapping your TitleBar.  You should let a margin or change MaxWidth of your TabView depending on the window width.

Comment: When I change the MaxWidth of my TabView, the TabPages are getting resized too. So in the sample they used the TabStripFooter to create a Grid with a specified Width as the Titlebar and also to create a space from the Minimize, Close and Maximize buttons, but for me the space is not working

Comment: I tried your code in a blank project but I could not reproduce this behavior. Did you customize your titlebar?

Comment: I have changed nothing, only used the code from Microsoft  and set the tabcount so high, that the tabs must overflow

Comment: Is it in a blank project? If you could reproduce this, please share more code snippets about this issue. The  code is not enough to reproduce this issue in a blank project.

Comment: I have updated my code and added a link to a github repo with the whole sample project

Comment: Well, after checking your code, actually you are customizing your titlebar as I guessed. Calling  `coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;` the view's content will extend into the title bar region. That's the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Oh i did not know. So is there a fix for this weird behavior?

Comment: Is it necessary to customize the title bar for you? If not, the simplest way is the set the `coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` property to false or directly remove this line of code.

Comment: Yeah it is necessary, but I actually have an idea, of how to fix it, but I am not able to try this now. My idea is, to add a loaded event to the customdragregion, and put the code from  OnNavigateTo into the loaded event. Now the tabs should only be loaded when the titlebar was created.

Comment: That should work. Or you could try to change the position of the tabview. Move the tabview controller a little bit lower by setting the margin.  This should be possible to fix this behavior as well.

Comment: I tried my solution and I think it works now, I mean I haven't had any problems after this change.

Comment: Glad to hear that. It will be appreciated if you could share your solution as an answer here. This might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you have to first add a Loaded event to your CustomDragRegion. Now you can remove the code from the OnNavigateTo function and paste it into the Loaded function. That's it.

```
private void CustomDragRegion_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Tabs.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // Extend into the titlebar
    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

    coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;

    var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent;

    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(CustomDragRegion);
    // Main Window - add some tabs
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        Tabs.TabItems.Add(CreateNewTVI($"Item {i}", $"Page {i}"));
    }
}
```